# How to allow Category Title to use <b> tags?

Tags: categories

I'd like to be able to use

```
<b></b>
```

within my Category Title in Wordpress but the admin strips them out.

I realise I can make the whole title bold using css but I only want it to apply to certain words.

Is there a way of enabling this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: How and in what part of the theme are categories being displayed?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can force the system to accept markup in the category titles, and I am not sure you should even try so I am going to suggest that you hack together a kind of markdown. Use some character like `*` as a placeholder then...

```
add_filter(
  'the_category',
  function($categories) {
    $pattern = '|(\*)([^\*]+)(\*)|';
    return preg_replace($pattern,'<b>$2</b>',$categories);
  }
);
```

I am not sure how robust that is. I am sure the callback could be much better but it works when I test it.

Also, a lot depends on how you are displaying the categories. I am not even sure if that is the filter you need. Your questions does not provide that information.